# C# Get object inside of object that is a generic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection

I have several View Models that contain a address object.  That address object of course has address1, address2, city, state, and zip.
We are using the postal code address verification system, and I want all of my developers to be able to call a helper class, that will sniff View Model object for a address object.  If it does not find it, it will then check to see if the view model has basic address1, address2 and etc properties...  In either case I need it to get the address information for either the property object address or get the address properties...

So my helper class method signature looks like this:

```
 public void ShowVerificationWithReflection<T>(ModelStateDictionary modelState, T viewModel) where T : AMSBaseVM
```

I then do the following:

```
var objType = viewModel.GetType();
List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

properties.AddRange(objType.GetProperties());

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.CanRead)
    {
        if (property.Name == "Address1") testAddress.Address1 = property.GetValue(viewModel, null) as string;
        if (property.Name == "Address2") testAddress.Address2 = property.GetValue(viewModel, null) as string;
        if (property.Name == "City") testAddress.City = property.GetValue(viewModel, null) as string;
        if (property.Name == "StCd") testAddress.StateCodeId = (long)property.GetValue(viewModel, null);
        if (property.Name == "Zip") testAddress.Zip = property.GetValue(viewModel, null) as string;
    }
}
```

This works for the address properties that part of the View Model.
Now what I am stumbling with is detecting if the View Model has a property like this:

```
 public EntityAddressVM Address { get; set; }
```

I need to get that object from the generic and then get its address properties.  I have been able to find the object, but after that I get stuck...

```
 bool hasEntityAddress = objType.GetProperties().Any(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(EntityAddressVM));
```

**What I am needing help with is:**

1. Determine if incoming viewModel (mvc) has a address object or has
   address properties.
2. If it does have address Object, get the address properties otherwise get the address properties from the ViewModel.

Comment: How about exchange the `Any` call with a `SingleOrDefault` call, to not just check if a property exists but getting it.

Comment: It is very old code 100+ view models and etc and we are not being allowed to refactor that deeply.  :(  Unfortunately, I do not have a deep knowledge of generics - try though to get up to speed.    But either way, even with generics I would still need to get the object address and parse the values.. I am stuck on that part.

Comment: It was mentioned by someone to use an interface to simplify the process.  After applying the answer below I continued to run into various points of pain.  So I took the suggestions and combined them with the answer below and it is all working smoothly now.  My interface has the properties all my classes and verification code needs and the winner is I was able to remove a ton of duplicate, over complex code and such.. Thanks for the pointers folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one nice extension method that I use to look at objects properties:

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets all public properties of an object and and puts them into dictionary.
/// </summary>
public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    // if an object is dynamic it will convert to IDictionary<string, object>
    var result = instance as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (result != null)
        return result;

    return instance.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(instance));
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var addressObject = model
    .ToDictionary()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value is EntityAddressVM)
    .Value;
```

If its `null` then get Address properties from model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting design time error, Method 'ToDictionary' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 2 arguments.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your `.cs` file

Comment: Added linq and changed the code a bit.... Testing now...
 return instance.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(instance,null));

Comment: Hmm, it is returning null.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the answer: `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value is EntityAddressVM).`. Notice the `x` changed to `x.Value`.